# django ManyToManyField and back?

Tags: django

I have two models like these:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.surname


class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    invited_people = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.pub_date)
```

so i can create many events and link a bunch of people to each ones

but in my Person detail template, how to get all events the Person attended to?

(i'm using the generic.DetailView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is [making queries on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships).

In a nutshell, you either specify a names you like in `related_name` keyword argument of `ManyToManyField` or use Django defaults like `your_event.person_set.all`.

Comment: so i need to create a function in my Person detail view like "get_events" with that query, right?

Comment: In a simplest case you don't have to - you could just write `{% for event in person.event_set.all %}...{% endfor %}` in your template. In case you need something more complex (like filtering), you should do that your view's `get_context_data`.